# Проблема сравнения данных из файла с вводом пользователя

Tags: python

Программа - викторина с 4 вариантами ответа . Для проведения игры нужно данные из текстового файла переместить по переменным . Данные представлены в файле в таком виде :

```
ТЕМА ВИКТОРИНЫ 
1 БЛОК ДАННЫХ
2 БЛОК ДАННЫХ 
...
```

Каждый блок - это

```
ТЕМА ВОПРОСА
ВОПРОС
1 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА
2 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА
3 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА 
4 ВАРИАНТ ОТВЕТА 
ПРАВИЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ 
КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ВОПРОСУ
```

Вот моя программа :

```
import sys

def open_file (way,mode,coding) :  
    """
    Проверяет наличие файла на нужном месте и открывает его
    """ 
    try : 
        f = open(way,mode,encoding=coding)
    except IOError as e : 
        print ("Невозможно открыть файл !\n")
        print ("Произошла ошибка : \n\t"+e)
        input ("Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти ...")
        sys.exit()
    else : 
        return f 

def welcome (f) : 
    """
    Приветствуем пользователя
    """
    print ("\t\tДобро пожаловать в игру \"Викторина\"\n")
    print (f.readline())

def data (f) : 
    """
    Распределяет данные по переменным
    """
    heading = f.readline() # заголовок
    question = f.readline() # вопрос
    answers = []  # список ответов
    for i in " "*4:
        answers.append(f.readline())
    true = f.readline() # правильный ответ
    comment = f.readline() # комментарий
    heading, question, answers, true, comment = heading, question, answers, true, comment.rstrip() # убираем из конца \n
    return heading , question , answers , true , comment

def game (f) :
    """
    Проводит игру и возвращает количество баллов
    """
    pools = 0

    # присваиваем данные переменным
    heading , question , answers , true , comment = data(f)
    while heading != "" :

        print (heading,"\n")
        print (question,"\n")

        number = 0
        for answer in answers  : 
            number += 1
            print(number, "-", answer)

        # принимаем ответ 
        user_answer = input ("Введите правильный ответ : ")

        # проверяем 
        if user_answer == true :
            pools += 1
            print ("Правильно !")
        else :
            print ("Неправильно !")
            print (user_answer == true , type(user_answer),user_answer,type(true),true) # узнаём тип данных и значение переменных
            print ("Правильный ответ -",true)

        print (comment) 
        # присваиваем данные переменным для следующего цикла
        heading , question , answers , true , comment = data(f)

    f.close()
    return pools

def end (pools) : 
    """
    Заканчивает игру
    """
    print ("\nВикторина окончена !")
    print ("\nВы набрали",pools,"баллов .")

def main () :
    """
    Запускает игру
    """
    f = open_file("quiz.txt","r","utf-8")
    welcome (f)
    pools = game(f)
    end(pools)

main()
input ("Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти ...")
```

Вот файл из которого я беру данные , в нём один блок

```
Столовая из 2008
Вкусный борщ , с капусткой , но не красный 
Что добавляется в борщ ? 
сосисочки
вкусный чай
непонятный салат
капуста 
4
Но чай - это сила !
```

Я запускаю программу , и вот что у меня получается :

```
                Добро пожаловать в игру "Викторина"

Столовая из 2008

Вкусный борщ , с капусткой , но не красный


Что добавляется в борщ ?


1 - сосисочки

2 - вкусный чай

3 - непонятный салат

4 - капуста

Введите правильный ответ : 4
Неправильно !
False <class 'str'> 4 <class 'str'> 4

Правильный ответ - 4

Но чай - это сила !

Викторина окончена !

Вы набрали 0 баллов .
Нажмите Enter , чтобы выйти ...
```

Я думал , что проблема в том , что "4" != "4\n" . Я удалил \n из конца каждой строки , но ничего не изменилось . Почему - то значения переменных одинаковы , тип тоже , но они не равны . Что это такое и как исправить ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант

```
 user_answer = int(input ("Введите правильный ответ : "))

        # проверяем 
        if user_answer == int(true) :
```

Второй вариант
в момент чтения из файла

```
 true = f.readline() # правильный ответ
 true=true[:-1]
```

Тогда сработает

```
if user_answer == true :
```

Дело именно в том, что у вас true='4\n'
Или в момент чтения храните сразу как число.